# I can't get resources using java class .error: Attempt to invoke virtual method

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, android-recyclerview

Any one can help me I can't find how I can fix this error 
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
```

/**
     * Created by Ineza on 18/11/2016.
   */

```
public class DerpData extends Application {
  private static Context mContext;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    mContext = this;
}

public static Context getContext(){
    return mContext;
}



private static final String[] titles  = DerpData.getContext().getResources().getStringArray(R.array.listArray);
private static final int[] icons =DerpData.getContext().getResources().getIntArray(R.array.imgs);


public static List<LisItem> getListData() {
    List<LisItem> data = new ArrayList<>();

    //Repeat process 4 times, so that we have enough data to demonstrate a scrollable
    //RecyclerView
    for (int x = 0; x < 4; x++) {
        //create ListItem with dummy data, then add them to our List
        for (int i = 0; i < titles.length && i < icons.length; i++) {
            LisItem item = new LisItem();
            item.setImageResId(icons[i]);
            item.setTittle(titles[i]);
            data.add(item);
        }
    }
    return data;
}
```

}

Here is a part of logcat

```
11-19 06:07:42.188 6497-6497/com.example.ineza.assthree E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.ineza.assthree, PID: 6497
    java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.example.ineza.assthree.RecyClerViewActivity.onCreate(RecyClerViewActivity.java:27)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6664)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference
    at com.example.ineza.assthree.model.DerpData.<clinit>(DerpData.java:30)
    at com.example.ineza.assthree.RecyClerViewActivity.onCreate(RecyClerViewActivity.java:27) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6664) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755) 
11-19 06:07:42.223 1326-1337/system_process W/ActivityManager:   Force    finishing activity com.example.ineza.assthree/.RecyClerViewActivity
11-19 06:07:42.284 1326-1337/system_process W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.example.ineza.assthree/.LVCustomActivity
11-19 06:07:42.348 1326-1326/system_process W/art: Long monitor contention with owner Binder:1326_1 (1337) at void com.android.server.am.AppErrors.crashApplicationInner(com.android.server.am.Proc essRecord, android.app.ApplicationErrorReport$CrashInfo)(AppErrors.java:328)  waiters=0 in int com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.broadcastIntent(android.app.IApplicationThread, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String, android.content.IIntentReceiver, int, java.lang.String, android.os.Bundle, java.lang.String[], int, android.os.Bundle, boolean, boolean, int) for 144ms
11-19 06:07:42.561 1326-1343/system_process E/BatteryStatsService: power:  Missing API
11-19 06:07:42.562 1326-1375/system_process D/WifiNative-HAL: Failing getSupportedFeatureset because HAL isn't started
11-19 06:07:42.569 1326-1343/system_process E/BluetoothAdapter: Bluetooth binder is null
11-19 06:07:42.571 1326-1343/system_process E/BatteryStatsService: no controller energy info supplied
11-19 06:07:42.620 1326-1343/system_process E/BatteryStatsService: modem info is invalid: ModemActivityInfo{ mTimestamp=0 mSleepTimeMs=0 mIdleTimeMs=0 mTxTimeMs[]=[0, 0, 0, 0, 0] mRxTimeMs=0 mEnergyUsed=0}
11-19 06:07:42.723 1326-2409/system_process I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
```

Comment: Can you add logcat?

Comment: It is done @emrekose26

Answer (score 1):

The code is trying to access static variable from static context when initializing the class. The static initializers are executed before any instance of the class is created. The mContext is initialized after the instance creation during the lifecycle callback. Change your code like this (**Updated** according to comment below):

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    mContext = this;
    titles  = mContext.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.listArray);
    icons = mContext.getResources().getIntArray(R.array.imgs);
}

private static final String[] titles;
private static final int[] icons;
```

Comment: Better to use `titles  = mContext.getResources()`